# How do I run a python project from anywhere on my computer without providing the full path?

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables, project

I have a python project that has a structure something like this:

```
TestProject
├── README.md
├── env
└── test_project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── file_1.py
    └── file_2.py
```

and I would like to be able to run it from anywhere on my file system just by calling

```
test_project --arg1 --arg2 --etc
```

The dream is to have a separate `experiments` directory where I can run my code while providing configs without having to type out the full path all the time.

I've added `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the top of my `__main__.py` file but I don't know what to add to what `$PATH` or `$PYTHONPATH` to make it work.

(I'm running on MacOS)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use 'cd' in the cmd to reach the directory your main is and then run your python file without any path

Comment: This is precisely what I don't what to do - i want to run it from a different directory as stated in the question

Comment: imao, creating an alias to the full path of the script in your terminal is easiest. [here's](https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/alias/#gsc.tab=0) a quick tutorial.

Comment: You can symlink or copy a file into somewhere that's available on your `$PATH`

Comment: just to be sure, you are on a linux system, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the alias command

```
alias your_command_name='python /path/to/script/your_script.py'
```

https://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/alias.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating an alias, you can also create a shell script.

In a file named `test_project.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
python /path/to/TestProject/test_project
```

Put that somewhere that's included in your $PATH variable, then run `test_project.sh`. You might have to mark it as executable (`chmod u+x test_project.sh`). You also don't need the `.sh` extension in your file name. I added it for clarity.